# PowerShell: Assigning a variable, while surpressing console output of dotnet user-secrets

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core

I am trying to run the following command inside a PowerShell script:

```
$settingsFile = dotnet user-secrets list -p "..\$project"
```

where `$project` is a string variable describing a `.csproj`-file.

When running the above command fails (as not every project will have user secrets) the following gets written to the output window:
`Could not find the global property 'UserSecretsId' in MSBuild project '<PATH_TO_CSPROJ>.csproj'. Ensure this property is set in the project or use the '--id' command line option.`

I want to suppress this output, while still being able to set the `$settingsFile` variable. How do I do this?
I have tried the following modifications, which all did not work for me:

**Try-catch**

```
try { $settingsFile = dotnet user-secrets list -p "..\$project"} catch{ }
```

This was taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42267294/2804432). However, this did not do anything.

**Redirect error stream with `Out-Null`**

```
$settingsFile = dotnet user-secrets list -p "..\$project" | Out-Null
```

This was taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60582407/2804432). However, this also did not change anything to the output.

**Redirect error stream with `Out-Null` and `2>&1`**

```
$settingsFile = dotnet user-secrets list -p "..\$project" 2>&1 | Out-Null
```

This did prevent the command from writing to console, but also caused the variable `$settingsFile` not to be set.

---

So, does anyone have any other ideas as how I might be able to achieve this goal? Let me know if there are any further questions regarding this issue.

Comment: `$settingsFile = dotnet user-secrets list -p "..\$project" 2>$null` <- you want to redirect _only_ the error stream to `$null`

Comment: Remove the "-p".    It is not a parameter.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretmanagement/get-secret?force_isolation=true&view=ps-modules

Comment: @jdweng, I am using `user-secrets` from the ASP.NET-Core package. I do understand the confusion however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the error stream to `$null`:

```
$settingsFile = dotnet user-secrets list -p "..\$project" 2>$null
```

Comment: Never came across that operator in my whole search. Do you have any nice resources about this? Thanks anyways. This fixed it.

Comment: @Rich_Rich The stream redirection operator (`>`)? You used it twice in your question :)